# Is it possible to pair two slightly different cards in SLI?

Tags: graphics-card, windows-vista, nvidia-graphics-card

I used to have 2 Nvidia 9800GT in SLI. Unfortunately, the fan on one of them broke down and the card pretty much just died.

Now I'd like to replace it, but for some reason this card even if it's old, is very expensive. At least for my budget.

So I was wondering if I could replace it with a slightly different card.

Right now I have [one like this](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product_geforce_9800gt_us.html) (like I said, I used to have 2), and I'd like to replace it with [this one](http://www.tigerdirect.ca/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=6460821&CatId=3670) (or another similar, I'm open to suggestions):

> ZOTAC ZT-98GES5P-FDL GeForce 9800 GT Video Card
>   512MB DDR3, PCI Express 2.0, DVI, HDMI, DirectX 10, OpenGL 2.1

Would this be possible, and are they going to work correctly in SLI?

**EDIT :** Before anyone suggests, I do not want to replace with a single, but more powerful card. I've read somewhere that my computer runs the graphic cards in 8x which I don't think is good for one card.

It's a Dell XPS 630i ; I don't have the exact specs right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are both the same processor (GeForce 9800GT) and have the same amount of memory, then you should be able to SLI them together.

That being said, the difference between running a card at 16x and running a card at 8x is [almost nonexistant](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/pci-express-2.0,1915-9.html) for any of today's games. Budget might still be a valid factor, but don't let the 8x/16x keep you from getting a better, single card if you can find and afford one. (And then you don't have to deal with all the weird quirks of SLI!)

(Thanks Breakthrough for the point about memory requirements)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, appreciate it.

So you're saying the difference between 8x and 16x doesn't really matter... the one thing that really bugged me is how hot my card would get after a couple hours of gaming.

I used to open my computer case and put a fan next to it to cool it down, am I just being paranoid ?

Comment: Also, I have one last little question. If I start looking for a better graphic card, considering my card was PCI Express 2.0, replacing it with any other card PCI Express 2.0 would be fine or is there any other compatibility issue I should be looking for ?

Comment: Possibly. Some of the older cards did operate at about 100C under full load. The newest ones run much cooler, in the 60-85C range. Just keep all the dust cleaned out and good airflow around the case and you should be good. As to the difference between 8x and 16x, it's roughly 3% or less-- a frame or two per second. Very few games involve loading massive amounts of data into video memory after the initial load, which is the only place you'd see a real benefit from that (or if a game requires more memory than the card can provide, but performance is horrible then anyways).

Comment: Any PCIe 1.0 or PCIe 2.0 card will work fine in any PCIe 2.0 or PCIe 1.0 slot. They're backwards and forwards compatible. That being said,  you do want to shoot for a PCIe 2.0 card.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot for your time. Really appreciate the help, Cheers !

Comment: Just to add, you can SLI any two video cards so long as they share the same GPU **and** have the same amount of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should work OK - though the new card will effectively be limited to the clock rates of the slower card.  Reference [Scalable Link Interface / Caveats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Link_Interface#Caveats) from Wikipedia.